# Key name of of marshaled slice of JSON objects needs to be lower case

Tags: json, go, struct, slice

How do I make the key name `Id` lower case in the marshaled JSON output for this code?

```golang
    type Topic struct {
        Id string
    }

    topics := []Topic{
        {Id: "some identifier"},
        {Id: "some other identifier"},
    }

    tops, err := json.Marshal(topics)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("got an error", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(tops))
```

Returns:

```golang
[
    {"Id":"some identifier"},
    {"Id":"some other identifier"}
]
```

But the API I'm using requires lower case, like:

```golang
[
    {"id":"some identifier"},
    {"id":"some other identifier"}
]
```

I am still pretty new to golang, so any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You just set the `json` struct tag

```
type Topic struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
}
```

Comment: You know, just as you answered, that very thought occurred to me, and I was about to delete the question.